# Sql Query finding local maximum

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a query that returns the name of an employee with the highest salary for each project. I have 3 tables:

1. Emp(Empno,Ename,Salary)
2. Proj(Projno, Pname)
3. Assertion Table between those 2 called Proj_Emp(Projno, Empno)

I made a query

```
    Select  pname, ename, sal
    from EMP, Proj_emp, PROJ
    where emp.empno= proj_emp.empno and proj_emp.projno=proj.projno
    and sal = (Select distinct Max(sal) from emp);
```

But it only returns a project where is the guy who has the biggest salary. For example

```
Pname       Ename   Salary
PROJECT2    KING    5000
```

And I Want to get all project with the guy who earns the most in each project. I bet that I'm missing something in that nested query but I don't know how to fix it. Could u pls help me.

I want to get for example:

```
Pname       Ename   Salary
PROJECT2    KING    5000
PROJECT1    KING    4000
PROJECT3    BARTOSZ 2000
PROJECT4    ANDY    1340
```

Comment: can you provide sample result which you want?

Comment: The problem is that `Select distinct Max(sal) from emp` returns the single largest salary value in the `emp` table. You then only find rows from your main query where the `sal` is equal to that maximum value. I can't think of a solution quickly but I hope that helps describe the problem better.

Comment: I added a sample.

Comment: `distinct Max(sal)` makes no sense to begin with `select max(sal) from ..` only returns a single row and a single column. So the `distinct` will not change anything

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please tag your request accordingly. Then, you are using a join syntax that was made redundant in 1992. Don't use comma-separated joins, but proper ANSI joins instead (`FROM emp INNER JOIN proj_emp ...`). And when working with multiple table, qualify all columns with their table names or aliases (`proj.pname` etc.). Please edit your request accordinly, so we see which tables the columns reside in.

Answer (score 2):

use row_number() which is supported by most dbms

```
  with cte as
   ( select p.Pname,e.Ename,e.salary
    ,row_number()over(partition by pe.Projno order by e.salaray desc) rn
     from Proj_Emp pe join Proj p on pe.Projno=p.Projno
                       join Emp e on e.Empno=pe.Empno
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: Better to use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` in case several people have the max salary in a project.

Comment: @FXD agreed but op not clear anything he needs ties or not with max salary that's why i prefer row_number()